# Android: Putting a custom permission on the main activity - bad practice?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have a simple application that runs a webview and I want it to be launchable by other applications sending a few parameters that I will include in the URL string.

To accomplish this, I created a new intent-filter on the main activity to go with the main/launcher intent-filter like so:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.intents.START_APP" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

So far so good, however, there's a twist.
I'd like to protect this activity from being run by anyone - I only want it to be run by other applications with the same signature that define a custom permission. To do that, I created a custom permission for the application like so:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.mycustompermission"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

and in the activity I added:

```
            android:permission="com.mycompany.myapp.mycustompermission"
```

This resulted in the following error in upon installation from APK and launching from the installer:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6702): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.mycompany.myapp cmp=com.mycompany.myapp/.myActivity } from ProcessRecord{41517d20 6702:com.android.packageinstaller/u0a56} (pid=6702, uid=10056) requires com.mycompany.myapp.mycustompermission
```

And a message on the screen saying:

```
Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped
```

My guess is that this is because the activity that launches the application from an intent can't be the main activity but rather has to be a separate activity but I couldn't find anything that proves that online.

My questions is - do you know this to be true - should I never put a custom signature level permission on the main (launchable) activity of the application?

Comment: If it's launchable, that means it will appear in the app list/drawer of the launcher. Requiring a custom permission means that in basically every launcher in the world, it would be a dead button. That's most likely the rationale behind it. If you made a custom launcher *with* that permission enabled, you could just call the intent directly without it being "launchable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I never put a custom signature level permission on the main (launchable) activity of the application?

Yes, unless you are the author of the home screen or other launcher and can ensure that it holds the custom permission. Otherwise, you may as well take off the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`, as it is advertising something ("hey, launch me!") that is not generally true.