# Custom Permission for activity

Tags: android

I created a custom permission in manifest file, in the same application for the launcher activity, gave this permission, and also set  tag, still my application is not launched, giving a securityException.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.permissionsbasics"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permissionsbasics.permission.TEST"
        android:label="@string/lable"
        android:description="@string/description"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permissionsbasics.permission.TEST" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.permissionsbasics.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.example.permissionsbasics.permission.TEST" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Exception :

```
[2014-11-02 20:18:42 - PermissionsBasics] ------------------------------
[2014-11-02 20:18:42 - PermissionsBasics] Android Launch!
[2014-11-02 20:18:42 - PermissionsBasics] adb is running normally.
[2014-11-02 20:18:42 - PermissionsBasics] Performing com.example.permissionsbasics.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-11-02 20:18:42 - PermissionsBasics] Automatic Target Mode: using device '050d923e09d38840'
[2014-11-02 20:18:42 - PermissionsBasics] Uploading PermissionsBasics.apk onto device '050d923e09d38840'
[2014-11-02 20:18:42 - PermissionsBasics] Installing PermissionsBasics.apk...
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] Success!
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] Starting activity com.example.permissionsbasics.MainActivity on device 050d923e09d38840
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.permissionsbasics/.MainActivity }
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.permissionsbasics/.MainActivity } from null (pid=20755, uid=2000) requires com.example.permissionsbasics.permission.TEST
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2133)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
[2014-11-02 20:18:47 - PermissionsBasics] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help ....

Answer (score 2):

Since your activity requires a custom permission, any app that doesn't have that permission will not be able to make a call to that activity.

The default launcher does not have any custom permissions, so when it tries to launch your app, it does not have authority to do so.

You just need to put the `android:permission` tag on a different activity.

And why would you want the "launcher" to use a custom permission? That essentially means it is a "public" permission and should be accessible publicly.

If you are interested in providing a "secure" launch, then you should have a public activity with a password or other authentication technique.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, You mean to say a launcher activity can never have a custom permission ?

Comment: I edited my response. Do you need more explanation for the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

More details on why you can't have custom permissions for a launcher activity is discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126687/android-putting-a-custom-permission-on-the-main-activity-bad-practice).